# Memory leak in DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5 via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, pinvoke, dhcp

I want to enumerate all DHCP Leases from our DHCP Server (Windows 2008 R2) via a C# (.NET 3.5, x86) application.

As there are unfortunately no DHCP Server Classes in .NET, I use P/Invoke (dhcpsapi.dll) to get data from the DHCP Server.

Everything's fine if I use the DhcpEnumSubnetClients function together with the DHCP_CLIENT_INFO and DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY structs.

But if I use the corresponding V5 functions and structs (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5, DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5 and DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5), I get a nasty memory leak (roughly around 280-290 Bytes per enumerated Lease).

I need to use the V5 versions since I need information from the DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5 structure which is not available in the DHCP_CLIENT_INFO structure (bClientType and AddressState).

After the call to DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5, I call DhcpRpcFreeMemory as required but DhcpRpcFreeMemory doesn't seem to do anything when used with DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5.

Is this a bug in .NET 3.5 or in dhcpsapi.dll or is something missing in my code?

Very grateful for any help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


class Program
{
    [DllImport("dhcpsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern UInt32 DhcpEnumSubnetClients(
    string ServerIpAddress,
    UInt32 SubnetAddress,
    ref UInt32 ResumeHandle,
    UInt32 PreferredMaximum,
    out IntPtr ClientInfo,
    out UInt32 ElementsRead,
    out UInt32 ElementsTotal);

    [DllImport("dhcpsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern UInt32 DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5(
    string ServerIpAddress,
    UInt32 SubnetAddress,
    ref UInt32 ResumeHandle,
    UInt32 PreferredMaximum,
    out IntPtr ClientInfo,
    out UInt32 ElementsRead,
    out UInt32 ElementsTotal);

    [DllImport("dhcpsapi.dll")]
    static extern void DhcpRpcFreeMemory(IntPtr BuffPtr);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5
    {
        public UInt32 NumElements;
        public IntPtr Elements;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5
    {
        public UInt32 ClientIpAddress;
        public UInt32 SubnetMask;
        public DHCP_CLIENT_UID ClientHardwareAddress;
        public string ClientName;
        public string ClientComment;
        public DATE_TIME ClientLeaseExpires;
        public DHCP_HOST_INFO OwnerHost;
        public byte bClientType;
        public byte AddressState;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY
    {
        public UInt32 NumElements;
        public IntPtr Elements;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct DHCP_CLIENT_INFO
    {
        public UInt32 ClientIpAddress;
        public UInt32 SubnetMask;
        public DHCP_CLIENT_UID ClientHardwareAddress;
        public string ClientName;
        public string ClientComment;
        public DATE_TIME ClientLeaseExpires;
        public DHCP_HOST_INFO OwnerHost;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DHCP_CLIENT_UID
    {
        public UInt32 DataLength;
        public IntPtr Data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DATE_TIME
    {
        public UInt32 dwLowDateTime;
        public UInt32 dwHighDateTime;
        public DATE_TIME(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date == DateTime.MaxValue)
            {
                this.dwLowDateTime = this.dwHighDateTime = UInt32.MaxValue;
                return;
            }
            if (date == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                this.dwLowDateTime = this.dwHighDateTime = UInt32.MinValue;
                return;
            }
            this.dwLowDateTime = (UInt32)(date.ToFileTime() & 0xFFFFFFFF);
            this.dwHighDateTime = (UInt32)((date.ToFileTime() & 0x7FFFFFFF00000000) >> 32);
        }
        public DateTime Convert()
        {
            if (this.dwHighDateTime == 0 && this.dwLowDateTime == 0)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            if (this.dwHighDateTime == int.MaxValue && this.dwLowDateTime == UInt32.MaxValue)
                return DateTime.MaxValue;
            return DateTime.FromFileTime((((long)this.dwHighDateTime) << 32) | (UInt32)this.dwLowDateTime);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Convert().ToString();
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct DHCP_HOST_INFO
    {
        public UInt32 IpAddress;
        public string NetBiosName;
        public string HostName;
    }




    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Main
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Server: ");
        string server = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Subnet: ");
        string subnet = Console.ReadLine();


        // 10 iterations for subnet with 150 leases:    5 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),     5 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 100 iterations for subnet with 150 leases:   7 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),    11 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 200 iterations for subnet with 150 leases:   7 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),    16 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 500 iterations for subnet with 150 leases:   7 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),    28 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // -> 40-45 KB leaked per iteration for DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5; 273-307 bytes per lease

        // 10 iterations for subnet with 1100 leases:   8 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),   11 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 100 iterations for subnet with 1100 leases:  8 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),   38 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 200 iterations for subnet with 1100 leases:  8 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),   68 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // 500 iterations for subnet with 1100 leases:  8 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClients),   157 MB RAM (DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5)
        // -> 305-307 KB leaked per iteration for DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5; 283-285 bytes per lease


        // -> around 280-290 bytes leaked per lease enumerated by DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            DataTable dhcpLeases = new DataTable();
            dhcpLeases = GetSubnetLeases(server, subnet);

            if (dhcpLeases == null || dhcpLeases.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Leases found");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < dhcpLeases.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MAC Address: " + dhcpLeases.Rows[i]["macAddress"] + ", IP Address: " + dhcpLeases.Rows[i]["ipAddress"]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(dhcpLeases.Rows.Count + " Leases found");
        }

        Console.Write("Any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }




    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Get all Leases for "subnet" on "server"
    // Returns DataTable containing Leases or null if there was a problem
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static DataTable GetSubnetLeases(string server, string subnet)
    {
        UInt32 response = 0, resumeHandle = 0;
        UInt32 nRead = 0, nTotal = 0;

        DataTable leases = new DataTable();
        leases.Columns.Add("ipAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("macAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("subnet");
        leases.Columns.Add("clientName");

        for (; ; )
        {
            IntPtr retPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // ---- Memory Leak ----
//            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClients(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // No Memory Leak

            if (response == 259)                                                //ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                break;
            }

            if (response != 0 && response != 234 || retPtr == IntPtr.Zero)      //ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                return null;
            }

            DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5 nativeArray = (DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5)Marshal.PtrToStructure(retPtr, typeof(DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5));   // ---- Memory Leak ----
//            DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY nativeArray = (DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(retPtr, typeof(DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY));          // No Memory Leak

            for (int i = 0; i < nativeArray.NumElements; i++)
            {
                IntPtr iPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(nativeArray.Elements, (i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))));

                DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5 nativeClient = (DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V5));  // ---- Memory Leak ----
//                DHCP_CLIENT_INFO nativeClient = (DHCP_CLIENT_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(DHCP_CLIENT_INFO));         // No Memory Leak

                string ipAddress = ConvertIP(nativeClient.ClientIpAddress);
                string clientName = nativeClient.ClientName;
                byte[] macBytes = new byte[nativeClient.ClientHardwareAddress.DataLength];
                Marshal.Copy(nativeClient.ClientHardwareAddress.Data, macBytes, 0, macBytes.Length);
                PhysicalAddress mac = new PhysicalAddress(macBytes);
                string macAddress = mac.ToString().ToUpper();
                macAddress = Regex.Replace(macAddress, "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})", "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6");

                leases.Rows.Add(ipAddress, macAddress, subnet, clientName);
            }

            if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
            if (response == 0) break;
        }
        return leases;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Convert IP Address in w.x.y.z format to UInt32
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static UInt32 ConvertIP(string ipString)
    {
        string[] ipArray = ipString.Split('.');
        UInt32 ipUint32 = (Convert.ToUInt32(ipArray[0]) * 16777216) + (Convert.ToUInt32(ipArray[1]) * 65536) + (Convert.ToUInt32(ipArray[2]) * 256) + (Convert.ToUInt32(ipArray[3]));
        return ipUint32;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Convert IP Address from UInt32 to string in w.x.y.z format
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static string ConvertIP(UInt32 ipUInt32)
    {
        string ipString = "";
        UInt32 octet = 0;

        octet = ipUInt32 / 16777216;
        ipString = ipString + octet.ToString() + ".";
        ipUInt32 = ipUInt32 - (octet * 16777216);

        octet = ipUInt32 / 65536;
        ipString = ipString + octet.ToString() + ".";
        ipUInt32 = ipUInt32 - (octet * 65536);

        octet = ipUInt32 / 256;
        ipString = ipString + octet.ToString() + ".";
        ipUInt32 = ipUInt32 - (octet * 256);

        ipString = ipString + ipUInt32.ToString();
        return ipString;
    }


}
```

**Edit:**
Even if I remove all code that uses the DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5 returned from DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5 (i.e. I'm only calling DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5 and don't care about what's returned), the memory leak is still the same.

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Get all Leases for "subnet" on "server"
    // Returns DataTable containing Leases or null if there was a problem
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static DataTable GetSubnetLeases(string server, string subnet)
    {
        UInt32 response = 0, resumeHandle = 0;
        UInt32 nRead = 0, nTotal = 0;

        DataTable leases = new DataTable();
        leases.Columns.Add("ipAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("macAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("subnet");
        leases.Columns.Add("clientName");

        for (; ; )
        {
            IntPtr retPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // ---- Memory Leak ----
//            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClients(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // No Memory Leak

            if (response == 259)                                                //ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                break;
            }

            if (response != 0 && response != 234 || retPtr == IntPtr.Zero)      //ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                return null;
            }

            if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
            if (response == 0) break;
        }

        leases.Rows.Add("1.1.1.1", "11:11:11:11:11:11", subnet, "clientName");
        return leases;
    }
```

**Edit:** Based on David Heffernan's input, I also tried to release the memory used by the Clients array before releasing the memory used by the whole struct, but it didn't help.

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Get all Leases for "subnet" on "server"
    // Returns DataTable containing Leases or null if there was a problem
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static DataTable GetSubnetLeases(string server, string subnet)
    {
        UInt32 response = 0, resumeHandle = 0;
        UInt32 nRead = 0, nTotal = 0;

        DataTable leases = new DataTable();
        leases.Columns.Add("ipAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("macAddress");
        leases.Columns.Add("subnet");
        leases.Columns.Add("clientName");

        for (; ; )
        {
            IntPtr retPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClientsV5(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // ---- Memory Leak ----
//            response = DhcpEnumSubnetClients(server, ConvertIP(subnet), ref resumeHandle, 65536, out retPtr, out nRead, out nTotal);      // No Memory Leak

            if (response == 259)                                                //ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                break;
            }

            if (response != 0 && response != 234 || retPtr == IntPtr.Zero)      //ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234
            {
                if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);
                return null;
            }


            IntPtr clientsArrayPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(retPtr, sizeof(UInt32));    // Get Pointer to the Clients Array

            if (clientsArrayPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(clientsArrayPtr); // Release Memory used by Cients Array
            if (retPtr != IntPtr.Zero) DhcpRpcFreeMemory(retPtr);                   // Release Memory used by the DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_ARRAY_V5 struct
            if (response == 0) break;
        }

        leases.Rows.Add("1.1.1.1", "11:11:11:11:11:11", subnet, "clientName");
        return leases;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, the documentation is really sparse. I wonder if you need to make two calls to the free function. The first one is passed the Clients field of the returned struct. And the second call is pass the pointer to the struct.

Comment: David, that didn't help unfortunately :-(